# Power BI: user input a parameter that refresh a SQL Query

Tags: powerbi, dax

So I'm working in creating a dashboard the refresh everytime a user set up s new parameter.

The SQL query that I'm running on running on a direct query load is the following:

`select * from dbo.userHistory where userid = jop1320`

The table mentioned above has multiple millions of rows and I want to filter the dashboard dinamically when an user change the userID.

I've went over and created a parameter for this and the code in power bi will look something like this

`select * from dbo.userHistory where userid = '"&userid&"'`

Now my question is, instead of the user going to transform data and click on edit parameters, is there a way that I can create a visual for the user to pass the userId that he wants to filter and then refresh the dataset?

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected output

Comment: Why using parameter and constructing a custom query? Why not let Power BI do the query generation for you? Assuming you are already using DirectQuery, just add a slicer on `userid` and Power BI will do the same.

Comment: @AndreyNikolov this is because I don't want the whole data to load on the backend as it will take a lot of time as the dataset is for 10 million or more rows.

Comment: @silentninja89 Actually, when using [DirectQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-directquery-about#directquery-connections) the data is not loaded, but Power BI will use [query folding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/power-query-folding) to construct pretty much the same query, which you are trying to use.